# how to use touch event X and Y to the same float point in glsurfaceview?

Tags: android

When i use  touch event.getX() value and event.getY() value to draw a rectangle in glsurfaceview. it gives me a wrong shape.

so how to get **the same point** of touched event.getX() and event.getY() on glsurfaceview ?

here is my rectangle vertices:

```
private float vertices[] = {  // Vertices for the rectangle
        rightBottomX, rightBottomY, pointZ,//right bottom
        rightTopX, rightTopY, pointZ, // right top
        leftBottomX, leftBottomY, pointZ,//left bottom
        leftTopX, leftTopY, pointZ // left top
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by "add 'f' to event.getX()" ?

Comment: sorry it's float ..i don't need to cast it.

Comment: Have You tried getRawX() and getRawY() instead? Some time ago that worked ffor me in GlSurfaceView.

Comment: thanks but glsurfaceview doesn't accept pixel only value between 1 and -1
i will put my solution down here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by two ways
first solution which i don't used :

pixel X in glsurfaceview float = (X * 2.0f / screenWidth - 1.0f);
pixel Y in glsurfaceview float = (Y * 2.0f / screenWidth + 1.0f);
not very good

second solution : the good solution :
i put my custom glsurfaceview in framelayout 
then i make another custom view from class drawing canvas and put it in the framelayout over the custom glsurafecview and drawing by x and y.
sorry if my english isn't good